# What should I do after changing DNS records and my site is not resolving?

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy, nameserver

My domain is not resolving after updating its DNS records 10 hours ago.

I bought the domain from GoDaddy and hosted it on a different server. They guided me to alter two domain entries: the first is an IP address, and the second is `ab.example.com`.

When I go to `example.com`, it is giving me the following error: `Webpage is unavailable`. Pinging my  website ends up with a timed out error and 100% loss for 4 packets.

It may be that I changed the nameservers three times in the last hour because of mistakes in the name. After that I set the nameservers to the default (`NS77.DOMAINCONTROL.COM` and
`NS78.DOMAINCONTROL.COM`), and changed the `A` host record and `CNAME` alias as directed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use Shift.

Comment: Remember DNS changes take time.  Always allow 4-24 hours.  Keep in mind browsers like to cache redirects, so try using ctrl-f5 to rwload the page and/or flush your computers DNS cache and the browser cache.

Comment: It can even take up to 48 hours or more (in some cases 72 hours). It's advisable to use online DNS health check and site access testing sites if you're still having problems.

Comment: You can check the DNS entries more directly by pointing your client computers networks settings to use the DNS servers of your DNS host. Please let us know if you still have trouble. I can possibly check your DNS entries tonight to make sure they make sense for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Different DNS entries and delegations have different TTLs (Time To Live). A typical TTL for a full domain (something.com) is 24 hours.

You can directly query the new authoritative DNS server directly if he has the intended records at all:

```
dig @newdns.server.com www.yoursite.com
```

Should give you an IP to the new host of your site, regardless of caching.

If after 24 hours or when entering this command your site still doesn't show up, you may have misconfigured something.
You would need to provide the complete zone file or a snap shot of the admin UI if you do not directly edit the zone file for further debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If the `A` records have been updated properly, try clearing the network/DNS cache on your local machine and see if it resolves the domain/subdomain to server IP address. If you are on a Windows machine, use the command below to clear the network/DNS cache:

`ipconfig /flushdns`

Answer (score 1):

**• Check if your DNS records are correct**

```
mydomain.com A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (Ipv4)
mydomain.com AAAA xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx (IpV6)
mysubdomain.mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.com (Alias)
```

See [Create and configure DNS records for a domain](http://en.open-lamp.com/create-and-configure-dns-records-for-a-domain/) on my blog for more information.

**• Flush your operating system's DNS cache**

```
ipconfig /flushdns (Windows)
/etc/init.d/nscd restart (Linux)
dscacheutil -flushcache (MacOS)
```

See [How to flush DNS cache in Linux / Windows / Mac](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-flush-dns-cache-in-linux-windows-mac) for more information.

**• Restart your modem**